# dirname(__FILE__) returns "/nfs" paths

Tags: php, path, nfs, dirname

I'm trying to get the directory name using this:

```
$d = dirname(__FILE__);
```

But it returns a NFS path. Anyone knows why it is happening?
My co-worker says that the NFS is off in the server.

Answer (score 0):

To check independently of your PHP script, where `__FILE__` really is, you can use

```
realpath /path/of/your/__FILE__
```

in a shell on the server.

Then, to tell, if it is an NFS file system, you can do:

```
stat -f -L -c %T /realpath/of/__FILE__
```

Probably your sysadmin moved the files to the path where the NFS was mounted before and symlinked them to the place where you access them.